# Laravel Job: how to ensure a very long timeout for a single job?

Tags: laravel, jobs, laravel-6

My webapp has a ton of jobs, all running well, exept one.

I need this particular job to survive a long time, a whole hour, 3600 seconds, and fails if over time, and do not retry.

I tried to setup this property in my job

```
public $timeout = 3600;     
public $retryAfter = 4000;  
public $tries = 1;
```

I obtained that after the fail this particula job is never retried, and it's ok.

But timeout and/or retryAfter are ignored. The job is marked as failed after a few minutes.

What am I doing wrong? 
Also, please, what is the differene from timeout and retryAftrer ?!?

### More info about my context

My queue is managed by supervisor as follows:

```
[program:projectname-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/appdemo.projectname.com/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/appdemo.projectname.com/storage/logs/laravel_worker.log
```

> This is the suggested configurations as per Lararavel's documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`public $timeout = 3600` will work only if you are running your queue with `queue:work`, but will not work if you use `queue:listen`.

Also, on `worker` level you have `--timeout` parameter where you can specify timeout on worker level, not just on job level, like this `php artisan queue:work --timeout=3600`.

However, you should definitely consider having a separate queue for the jobs that are time consuming, so that job should be queued on another queue, but all other not time consuming jobs can run on the one queue.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#customizing-the-queue-and-connection

Also, `timeout` defines for how long that job should be running, and `retryAfter` specifies after how much time it should try to run it again. Of course `tries` needs to be set to higher value, so it could retry.

Hope this helps.

Comment: retryAfter is not calculated from the failing of a job, but from THE START of a failing job or NOT ENDING job.

Answer (score 1):

A long running job may have several factors playing into why it fails early:

- The timeout specified by the application itself
- The timeout specified by the PHP config
- The timeout specified by the queue worker

Take a look into each of these to see where your bottleneck may be. Bear in mind, setups will vary from server to server.

Comment: wrong: retryAfter is calculcated from start of a job. This is why documentation tell to have retryAfter a bit longer than timeout

Comment: Huh, good spot. They hadn't added that to the docs when I last checked (back in 5.1). I've removed it to stop confusion!